# How relevant is the Lucene in Action book and field index analyzed parameter API change in 6.x

Tags: lucene

I am reading lucene in action 2nd edition, how relevant is this book considering we are now in version 6.x?

I was reading it and noticed there is a change in the API regarding Field.Index.  How is this done in 6.x now?

```
doc.add(new Field("city", "Den Haag",
                  Field.Store.YES,
                  Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying concepts should be reasonably useful. The general information on things like analysis (which seems to be a common stumbling block) are going to be broadly similar to the current version.

The code, however, is going to be woefully outdated, and you should expect to have to modify it heavily if you want to make it work. There have been *considerable* changes to the APIs since 3.X, and you have found just one of them, how fields are defined, which was overhauled in 4.0. If you want to make the code work, I would recommend you be ready to do some reading of the 6.6 APIs, and give a good going over to the migration guides:

- [4.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html)
- [5.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/MIGRATE.html)
- [6.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/MIGRATE.html)

Opening readers and writers, defining fields, creating queries, and writing custom analyzers are some of the central tasks that have changed in incompatible ways since 3.X.

For the example you've given, you could replace that with:

```
doc.add(new TextField("city", "Den Haag", Field.Store.YES));
```

See the section titled "Separate IndexableFieldType from Field instances", in the 4.0 Migration Guide.

Comment: So the idea of being analyzed but not indexed, or indexed but not stored dont' exist anymore?

Comment: No, still around. The different [Field](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) subclasses (like TextField) handle most common cases, and if you want to manage the whole field configuration, you can generate your own [FieldType](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html), and pass it to the Field ctor.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty outdated as i see.

You usually should use different subclasses of Field. In the Javadoc documentation you see the different types of fields:
 http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html

Use this types based on your needs and read the Javadoc properly.
There are some relevant informations like StringField will not be tokenized.

Here some examples based on your code example:

Stringfield:

```
luceneDocument.add(new StringField("name", "value", Field.Store.YES));
```

TextField:

```
luceneDocument.add(new TextField("name", "value", Field.Store.YES));
```

StoredField with int:

```
luceneDocument.add(new StoredField("name", intValue));
```

If this Fields do not fit your need, you're free to override Field and create your own Field classes, but i never used this.